# Trigger from cell modification on specific sheet

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, triggers

I have a spreadsheet called Project with two different sheets: P1 and P2
I need to Trigger a function when cell A1 of sheet P2 is modified. I print in B2 of P2 the words "it worked" and call the function

My code is as follows:

```
function onEdit(e) {
 if(e.range.getA1Notation() == 'A1' && e.range.getSheet.getName() == 'P2'){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("P2");
 sheet.getRange(2, 2).setValue('It worked')
 //call function
 }
};
```

However, my code is triggering the function also when A1 in P1 is modified.
I don't know where is my mistake

Help

Comment: you missed parenthesis after getSheet: e.range.getSheet().getName(), but this is probably not the solution because it should never trigger the update, neither for P1 nor P2

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //this function requires less function calls
  const sh = e.range.getSheet()
  if (e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 1 && sh.getName() == 'P2') {
    sh.getRange(2, 2).setValue('It worked');
    //call function
  }
}
```

But keep in mind this only works on user edits not on changes made by formulas or other triggers.

Comment: Hi @Cooper, thanks for your answer. Actually it did not work since the edit is made by a script in the (1,1) position. I guess onEdit(e) function does not see this as a user edit. Is there a work arround?

Comment: None that I know of.